# AutoResetEvent does not stop when I Set it

Tags: c#, multithreading, .net-3.5, timeout, autoresetevent

I'm trying to use `AutoResetEvent` in order to make an action or leave if it takes too much time.

This is the code I'm running :

```
TimeoutAction action = new TimeoutAction(1000, OuvrirDrawer);
action.Start();
```

And this is my `TimeoutAction` class :

```
public class TimeoutAction
{
    private Thread ActionThread { get; set; }
    private Thread TimeoutThread { get; set; }
    private AutoResetEvent ThreadSynchronizer { get; set; }
    private bool _success;
    private bool _timout;

    public TimeoutAction(int waitLimit, Action action)
    {
        ThreadSynchronizer = new AutoResetEvent(false);

        ActionThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(delegate
        {
            action.Invoke();
            if (_timout) return;
            _timout = false;
            _success = true;
            ThreadSynchronizer.Set();
        }));

        TimeoutThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(delegate
        {
            Thread.Sleep(waitLimit);
            if (_success) return;
            _timout = true;
            _success = false;

            ThreadSynchronizer.Set();
        }));
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// If the action takes longer than the wait limit, this will throw a TimeoutException
    /// </summary>
    public void Start()
    {
        ActionThread.Start();
        TimeoutThread.Start();

        ThreadSynchronizer.WaitOne();

        if (_success)
        {
            // TODO when action has completed
        }

        ThreadSynchronizer.Close();
    }
}
```

I espected it to take 1000ms max, because the `TimeoutAction` is going to send a signal after 1000ms.
So even if the method `OuvrirDrawer` is taking 5 seconds, I'm supposed to reach my TODO line after about 1000ms.
Well, guess what, it's not.

My method `OuvrirDrawer` is trying to open my cashdrawer but when it's not connected to my computer, it crashes.
I've put an empty catch but when it's trying to open it anyway, it takes a while (5 seconds).

With my code above, I wanted to timeout at 1 sec, I don't want to wait 5 seconds for it to see that my cashdrawer is NOT connected. One second is clearly enough.

Comment: Is `OurirDrawer` the action you're passing to `ActionThread`?

Comment: yes, it's the action I want to perform.

Comment: Well, your `action` is a synchronous operation which blocks. How do you expect anything to make it timeout after 1000ms?

Comment: Nothing very obvious about not getting the timeout to work.  It is buggy, the if (_timout) check is a race condition that gets your code to crash when it tries to call Set() on a disposed object.  It allows OuvrirDrawer() to be called when it is still executing, that rarely ends well.  Using a thread instead of the WaitOne(int) overload loses a lot of elegance points.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this without a timeout thread and without an event:

```
ActionThread.Start();
if (ActionThread.Join(1000))
{
    // thread completed successfully
}
else
{
    // timed out
}
```

See documentation for [Thread.Join](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6b1kkss0%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).